# How can we inflate particular menu item in android dynamically with a layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have used the below code to set the background but it is applying it to whole menu not to one menu item. Can we modify the below code to inflate only one menu item...

```
protected void setMenuBackground(){                      
    // Log.d(TAG, "Enterting setMenuBackGround");   
    getLayoutInflater().setFactory( new Factory() {   
        public View onCreateView(String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs) { 
            if ( name.equalsIgnoreCase( "com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView" ) ) { 
                try { // Ask our inflater to create the view   
                    LayoutInflater f = getLayoutInflater();   
                    final View view = f.createView( name, null, attrs );   
                    /* The background gets refreshed each time a new item is added the options menu.   
                    * So each time Android applies the default background we need to set our own   
                    * background. This is done using a thread giving the background change as runnable  
                    * object */ 
                    new Handler().post( new Runnable() {   
                        public void run () {   
                            // sets the background color    
                            view.setBackgroundResource( R.color.androidcolor); 
                            // sets the text color               
                            ((TextView) view).setTextColor(Color.BLACK); 
                            // sets the text size               
                            ((TextView) view).setTextSize(18); 
            } 
                    } );   
                return view; 
            } 
        catch ( InflateException e ) {} 
        catch ( ClassNotFoundException e ) {}   
   }  
    return null; 
});
```